# Duplicate printer entry on print?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing

I have one printer installed:

[image]

However, when I actually print a file, I can select between two similar named printers:

[image]

If I selecet `Lexmark-MC3224adwe` my pc just waits forever saying `Getting printer information...` :
[image: Lexmark-MC3224adwe]

How can I remove the entry `Lexmark-MC3224adwe`? Its not listed at `Printers`.

Comment: Do you see that extra printer when you go to the web page http://localhost:631/printers ? Can you delete it from there?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli unfortunatly not, it just displays Lexmark_** not Lexmark-**

Comment: I think your printer uses another protocol also and Ubuntu discovers it as another printer. Turn off (power off) your printer and the `Lexmark-MC3224adwe` will disappear. However, it will reappear when you turn it back on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This entry cannot be removed without crippling the printing experience; it is a consequence of the way the GTK print dialog works. The dialog does not need CUPS to discover IPP printers but manages it by itself with the aid of avahi-daemon. @FedonKadifeli hints at this.

More detail is on [this page.](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting#gtk)